# Win7 IE9 youtube player js object doesn't have any methods

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

My code that fetches a Youtube player works in all browsers except IE9 on Win7:

```
var myPlayer;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    myPlayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
        width: dimensions.width,
        height: dimensions.height,
        videoId: id,
        playerVars : {
            showinfo: 0,
            hl: playerLang,
            autoplay: 1,
            wmode: 'transparent',
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            rel: false
        }
    });
}
```

[Here is a longer code sample, closer to what I'm doing](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqKQVb).  I tried putting it in the snippet editor in the question, but it seems to hang my tab when I try to run it.

When I later try to call something like: `myPlayer.pauseVideo()` or `myPlayer.loadVideoById(options)`, I get a `TypeError` like:

`TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'loadVideoById'`

If I enumerate the keys of the `myPlayer` object, the methods do not exist.  When I test for the methods, they do not exist.

I found that I can send messages directly to the YouTube iframe successfully:

```
$('#ytplayer')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(
  '{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*'
);
```

Is there a way to get the player working properly in IE9?  This seems to be a recent breakage that the [changelog](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Revision_History) doesn't say anything about.

Also, this is a controlled environment.  No, at this time I can't switch from IE9 and Win7.  There are no extensions installed on the browser.  I have confirmed this in a vanilla installed browser and in Browserstack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to YouTubeIframeAPIReady event. Like this:

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady =  function() {
  // you can call function create new player here.
}
```

After youtube api js file load, onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function will be called.

Comment: Yes, sorry.   This is already happening before the create player is called.  I will amend my question to include to full code sample.